# How to combine two select statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to combine two select statement into single select statement

Select #1:

```
 SELECT 
    Product_Name as [Product Name], Product_Id as [Product Id]
 from 
    tb_new_product_Name_id
 where  
    Product_Name LIKE '%' + @product_name_id + '%' 
    or Product_Id like '%' + @product_name_id + '%' ;
```

Select #2:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Product_id) + 1 as duplicate_id
FROM 
    tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE 
    Product_id = (SELECT  Product_id
                  FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                  WHERE Product_Name = @product_name_id);
```

How to combine above two query into single select statement.i need to display three columns duplicate_id,[Product Name],[Product Id] .thanks..

Comment: What would you like the desire results to  look like?

Comment: i need to display three columns duplicate_id,[Product Name],[Product Id]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results?  I don't exactly see what you are trying to do.

Comment: got answer thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT A.Product_Name AS [Product Name], A.Product_Id AS [Product Id], B.duplicate_id
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id AS A, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 AS duplicate_id
    FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
    WHERE Product_id= (SELECT  Product_id
                       FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                       WHERE Product_Name=@product_name_id
                     )
) AS B
WHERE  A.Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' OR Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subquery` to get your desired results

```
SELECT 
    Product_Name as [Product Name], Product_Id as [Product Id],(SELECT 
    COUNT(Product_id) + 1 as duplicate_id FROM 
    tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
    WHERE 
    Product_id = (SELECT  Product_id
                  FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                  WHERE Product_Name = @product_name_id)) as duplicate_id 
 from 
    tb_new_product_Name_id
 where  
    Product_Name LIKE '%' + @product_name_id + '%' 
    or Product_Id like '%' + @product_name_id + '%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 as duplicate_id
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE Product_id= (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' or
                         Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%'
                 );
```

Comment: i need to display three columns duplicate_id,[Product Name],[Product Id]